# Laravel / PHP Language Code Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, sorting

I have some languages stored in my database as follows:

```
id | code  | name 
--------------------------------------
1  | en_GB | English, United Kingdom
2  | pt_BR | Portugese, Brazil
3  | it_IT | Italian, Italy
4  | hi_IN | Hindi, India
5  | es_BR | Spanish, Brazil
6  | ur_IN | Urdu, India
```

I want to get these results and sort (or sort after I get all results), so I get the results first by ordered Country Code (second part of code) and then by Locale Code (first part of code) so:

```
$languages = [
    0 => [
       'code' => 'es_BR'
    ],
    1 => [
       'code' => 'pt_BR'
    ],
    2 => [
       'code' => 'en_GB'
    ],
    3 => [
       'code' => 'hi_IN'
    ],
    4 => [
       'code' => 'ur_IN'
    ],
    5 => [
       'code' => 'it_IT'
    ]
];
```

I've tried looping through each language and taking out the second part and storing an array of the Country Codes and then sorting them using `asort($countryCodes);`, which did sort by Country Code (GB), but I'm stuck sorting that list out by Locale Code (en).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does you try any code so far?

Comment: Have you check or not?

Comment: Am I getting down votes because people couldn't answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with the following and it has given me what I needed:

```
$languages = $this->getOrderedLanguages();

protected function getOrderedLanguages() 
{
    $languages = Language::orderBy('code')->get();

    // Sort out the other languages by country code (e.g. sort by GB in code en_GB)
    // Create array for each country code and store array key from original list
    $countryCodes = [];
    foreach($languages as $key => $language) {
        $countryCodes[$language->locale_code][] = [
            'id' => $key,
            'language' => $language->language_code
        ];
    }
    ksort($countryCodes);

    $orderedLanguages = [];

    // Go through each country code and sort the languages in there by locale code (e.g. sort by en in code en_GB)
    foreach($countryCodes as &$countryCode) {
        asort($countryCode);
        foreach($countryCode as $language) {
            $orderedLanguages[] = $allLanguages[$language['id']];
        }
    }

    // Return ordered array
    return $orderedLanguages;
}
```

This has given me the following result:

```
$languages = [
    0 => [
        'code' => 'es_BR'
    ],
    1 => [
        'code' => 'pt_BR'
    ],
    2 => [
        'code' => 'en_GB'
    ],
    3 => [
        'code' => 'hi_IN'
    ],
    4 => [
        'code' => 'ur_IN'
    ],
    5 => [
        'code' => 'it_IT'
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess [array_multisort](http://php.net/array_multisort) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I thought it might be this at first, but array_multisort requires a code to be in separate fields? How would I apply array_multisort to get what I am looking for?

Comment: #@Mehul Kuriya : FYI This is also sort and simple answer  ...!

Answer (score 0):

You would use usort() - http://php.net/usort

My suggestion would be:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a["code"], $b["code"]);
}

usort($languages, "cmp");
print_r($languages);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I got the following result: `en_GB, es_BR, hi_IN, it_IT, pt_BR, ur_IN`, so the original order from the DB

Comment: and your expected would be?

Comment: `es_BR, pt_BR, en_GB, hi_IN, ur_IN, it_IT`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with other version of code :

```
$fArray=array();
foreach($languages as $languages){
   array_push($fArray,$languages);
}
sort($fArray);
print_r($fArray);  

`OR`

array_multisort($languages);
print_r($languages);
```

Following are the generated array for both function :

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [code] => en_GB
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => es_BR
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [code] => hi_IN
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [code] => it_IT
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [code] => pt_BR
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [code] => ur_IN
    )

)
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for, this is just ordered by database id

Comment: Then what are you looking for?

Comment: which did sort by Country Code (GB), but I'm stuck sorting that list out by Locale Code (en). What does it mean ?

Comment: so it should first sort the list by the second part of the country code (the GB part) and then within that sort by the locale code (the en part) so I should have the following: `es_BR, pt_BR, en_GB, hi_IN, ur_IN, it_IT`. So it is sorted by BR, GB, IN & IT and within that it is sorted by the first part (es before pt for BR)